# Firefox Form submit issue with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, forms, firefox

I am using the following script to submit a form with jQuery, however Firefox has generated a crash error report, please let me know what am I doing wrong.

```
function teamValidation(){
    var cat_id = $('#cat_id').val();    

    if(cat_id == "0"){
        alert("Category is invalid...");    
        return false;
    }else{
        $('#addForm').submit(); 
        return false;
    }
}

<form action="<?php echo SITE_URL; ?>adminteams/saveDetail/" 
 name="addForm" id="addForm" onsubmit="return teamValidation();">
 <input type="hidden" name="cat_id" id="cat_id" value="1"/>
</form>
```

Firefox error report

[image]

It is working fine in other browsers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is your form is submitting multiple times.You can achieve your goal using any of the following ways:
HTML:

```
<form action="<?php echo SITE_URL; ?>adminteams/saveDetail/" name="addForm" id="addForm">
 <input type="hidden" name="cat_id" id="cat_id" value="1"/>
</form>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$('#addForm').submit(function(){
    var cat_id = $('#cat_id').val();    

    if(cat_id == "0"){
        alert("Category is invalid...");    
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
});
```

Another Way:
HTML:

```
<form action="<?php echo SITE_URL; ?>adminteams/saveDetail/" name="addForm" id="addForm" onsubmit="return teamValidation();">
     <input type="hidden" name="cat_id" id="cat_id" value="1"/>
    </form>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function teamValidation(){
    var cat_id = $('#cat_id').val();    

    if(cat_id == "0"){
        alert("Category is invalid...");    
        return false;
    }else{
       return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have an infinite loop of submitting, then preventing the submission of, your form when the value of the `cat_id` text box is not 0. Remove the `else` block, since it serves no actual purpose.

To go into more detail:

```
function teamValidation(){
    var cat_id = $('#cat_id').val();    

    if(cat_id == "0"){
        alert("Category is invalid...");    
        return false;
    }else{
        $('#addForm').submit(); // this submits the form again - does NOT proceed with this submission of the form
        return false; // returning false will prevent the submission from being completed
    }
}

<form action="<?php echo SITE_URL; ?>adminteams/saveDetail/" 
 name="addForm" id="addForm" onsubmit="return teamValidation();">
 <input type="hidden" name="cat_id" id="cat_id" value="1"/>
</form>
```

When you submit the form, `teamValidation()` gets called. If the validation passes (the `else` block code is executed), you submit the form again **which causes `teamValidation()` to be called yet again**, then `return false` which will prevent this current submission from completing. Firefox is likely crashing because it finds itself in a loop where it's constantly submitting a form, which is never allowed to complete; the fact the browser is pretty awful in terms of memory usage probably doesn't help either.

Comment: @Samad Yes, there is. You call `teamValidation()` when you submit the form. In the else block, you do `$('#addForm').submit()` which **submits the form again**, then `return false` which **prevents the submission from being completed**.

Comment: i m using this script for other validation

Comment: @Samad You asked what you were doing wrong, and I've told you. If you want to refuse to correct your code and see if it fixes the problem, that's up to you.

Comment: This is not a coding issue because other browser has executed this code like chorme,safari and etc

Comment: how about this code document.getElemetBYId('addForm').submit();

Comment: @Samad That's the regular Javascript equivalent of `$('#addForm').submit()` - it does the same thing and will have the exact same problem. You **DO NOT** need to submit a form in the `onsubmit` callback function **for the exact same form**; it makes absolutely no sense to do so.

Comment: @Samad, unfortunately, you have to agree that there is unlimited recursion in your code.

Comment: $('#addForm').submit() is causing recursion but document.getElemetBYId('addForm').submit(); will not.... I have tested...

Comment: @ahmedtabrez Interesting that using the regular Javascript equivalent doesn't invoke the non-jQuery bound `onsubmit` event handler.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close your function definition

```
function teamValidation(){
    var cat_id = $('#cat_id').val();    

    if(cat_id == "0"){
        alert("Category is invalid...");    
        return false;
    }else{
        $('#addForm').submit(); 
        return false;
    }
} <--- this
```

Comment: This is not an issue of } i just forget this when i put this question in stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

You missed a '}' at the end. Still, It should not cause a crash.
99% a problem with your Firefox Installation. I just checked with mine here. Works correctly. There is no problem with your code. Try Uninstalling and reinstalling Firefox.

Another discovery. Your form is being submitted indefinitely. Maybe your other browsers are newer and your Firefox is outdated (not capable of handling indefinite recursions which is why it may be crashing).

Anyways, try replacing the following:

```
$('#addForm').submit();
```

with:

```
document.getElementById("addForm").submit();
```

Hope that helps..

Peace be upon you...

Comment: This is not an issue of } i just forget this when i put this question in stackoverflow

Comment: Browsers are designed to cope up with javascript errors. Browsers stop execution of Javascript if they find errors. Crashing due to Javascript bugs is not a thing of today. Sorry to say but There is surely a problem with your installation.

Comment: @ahmedtabrez I beg to differ - see my answer. There's a huge logical flaw with the code, that results in the form being submitted over and over again (rather than the single submission being allowed to proceed) when the validation passes.